# How to collapse array in MongoDB if current element are not equal previous?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can i collapse array in MongoDB, with specified condition if previous element not equal to current element?

Something like this:

```
["A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"] -> ["A", "B", "A", "B"]
```

Do not store first element because 0-index-element is A and 1-index-element is also A. And do not store 2-index-element because next is same.

Otherwise, i need to count how many times was changed elements in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            a: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$a",
                    initialValue: [{ $first: "$a" }],
                    in: {
                        $cond: { 
                            if: { $eq: [{ $last: "$$value" }, "$$this"] }, 
                            then: "$$value", 
                            else: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Test data 1:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6048e7643db2b733e846ea47"),
    "a" : ["A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"]
}
```

Output for Test-data-1:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6048e7643db2b733e846ea47"),
    "a" : ["A", "B", "A", "B"]
}
```

Test data 2:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6048e78a3db2b733e846ea48"),
    "a" : ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "D"]
}
```

Output for Test-data-2:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6048e78a3db2b733e846ea48"),
    "a" : ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
}
```